# Does Teemo's, Cassiopeia's, and Singed's poison stack?

Tags: league-of-legends

Does Teemo's, Cassiopeia's, and Singed's poison stack, or does the stronger poison tack over, or is it the last one how hit the enemy with poison get it, or what?

Comment: Poison is a damage classification - some damage is poison damage, but the fact that it's poison damage doesn't mean it takes up a theoretical "poison debuff" slot. Same way Ashe arrows can trigger double damage from Anivia's E.

Answer (score 1):

It all stacks, so the champ will take damage from each skill used on him.

Comment: It does!!!  That is good to know.  I been wondering if it did for a while, but no one know if it did or not!!!  Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the damage from the poisons stack, and for Cassiopeia's abilities any poison counts for the additional effect.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cassiopeia_the_Serpent%E2%80%99s_Embrace/Ability_Details

Answer (score 1):

All damage spells stack.  Ignite's damage stacks but it does not stack the 50% healing reduction,  a person can only be at 50% healing reduction no matter how many ignites are on you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually teemo's "e" does not stack according to [lol wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Teemo): "This poison will not stack but the duration will be refreshed with every subsequent attack."

There used to be a bug where Teemo attacked so fast that he never got the poison to activate. This was fixed in the Hecarim/Varus Skills and Stats + Patch Changes in April 2012.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.. Also, Teemo's shrooms do not stack. So if you put 5 shrooms in one place and someone steps into it, it's a waste of 4 shrooms since they will not do 5 times the damage but only 4 seconds of damage as if someone stepped into a single shroom..